# Javascript splice for array of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var myArray = [];
myArray = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
```

And when I called myArray.splice - it was undefined. How can I avoid this? I need remove some of DOM elements from that array.

Comment: can you show us the HTML code, with class selected?

Comment: myArray is a Nodelist not a normal array

Comment: I hope you're not imagining that removing elements from the node list is going to remove them from the document. Why do you want to remove elements from the array?

Comment: @torazaburo, I don't imaging this. I just want to delete some elements from myArray.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `querySelectorAll(..)` returns a list of nodes (`NodeList`) -- not a standard JS array.

May be you'd want something like below:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.selected'),  <begin>, <end>);
```

---

**UPDATE**

I missed the portion where you are trying to delete, thanks @torazaburo. Fortunately, you can directly apply filter on the NodeList instead of going via an array conversion. Something like below:

```
var arrayOfNodes = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll(".selected"), function(curNodeItem) {
     return shouldCurrentNodeBeRetained(curNodeItem)? true : false;
    //expanded for clarity.    
});
```

Comment: He's trying to call `splice` to remove elements, not `slice` to select them.

Answer (score 6):

`querySelectorAll` is a `NodeList` [array-like collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like), but it's not an array, since it doesn't inherit from `Array.prototype`. To convert it to real array you would use `slice` this way:

```
var myArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.selected'));
```

It is possible to use `slice` like this due to the fact that [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is intentionally generic method, meaning that it's internal implementation doesn't check if `this` value is actually `Array` instance. So `slice` can be used with any array-like objects, having numeric indexes and `length` property.

Answer (score 1):

[document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an Array.

Hence there is no [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method on NodeList By default.

However you can prototype similar method for A node list.

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elennaro/31obqwkn/1/), it removes elements like splice directly from DOM, you can modify it however you wish.

```
var myArray = [];
myArray = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');

//This is a primitive analogue of splice without adding new elements, it will not remove element from NodeList, however will remove it directly from dome, then it will return the resulting array (As Array), because NodeList is unmodifiable;
NodeList.prototype.splice = function(pos, numToRemove){
    var initRemCount = remCount = numToRemove ? numToRemove : 1;
    var removed = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        if(!remCount)
            break;
        var elm = this[i];
        if(i >= pos){
            //elm.parentElement.removeChild(elm); //I commented this out, 'cause you say you dont want to delete members from DOM, uncomment this to do so
            remCount--;
        }
    }
    return [].slice.call(this, pos, pos + initRemCount); 
}

var resultArray = myArray.splice(2, 2);

//This is the Araay already not a NodeList
console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: It's hardly necessary to pollute the `NodeList` prototype with a new routine (especially one that is enumrable), when you can simply convert the nodelist to an array. Also, the OP has said he does not want the elements removed from the DOM. Finally, this implementation departs from the `Array.splice` API by not handling the additional arguments for adding new elements.

Comment: Good, notice. Sorry I didn't mention that objects must stay in DOM. However cal you clarify first part of your comment.

Comment: What I meant was this issue is almost always handled by converting the nodelist to an array; then you can use the existing `Array#splice` directly. Your solution will work fine, but I doubt it you want to put all array methods on NodeList, which is the direction this would be taking you.

Comment: @torazaburo I Agree. Hovewer [MDN almost suggests this someway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_can%27t_I_use_forEach_or_map_on_a_NodeList.3F). Do you suggest me to edit my solution.

Comment: I'd say MDN "presents" it, not "suggests" it, and it gives the caveat that "extending the DOM is dangerous", but it's still one way to go about things so no, I don't think you have to edit it.

Comment: OK. Thank you, for very important comments. It's a pleasure to talk to such expert.